# Limiting access to text-to-speech API in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm using text-to-speech API on Google Cloud. I'm used with service accounts, roles or API Keys on GCP, but I feel lost with this AP and don't understand how I can set the permission to access this API.

The API forbid anonymous call, but I tried to create a service account with no specific permission, and it can access the API. Have this API only project level permission (API enabled or not)? How can I set what account can access the API?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Cloud Platform the restriction works the other way around than what you described, you create Service Account and you limit to what resource they can access. Please see documents: [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) and [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)  to learn more, and specifically [Permissions for service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#permissions_for_service_accounts) to learn how to restrict permissions on your Service Accounts.

Added to the above, [this API Console Help document](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7037264?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279) contains best practices and further information on API security